# How to add qdate to qtableview

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qdatetime

I want to add `Qdate` to my table say `QTableview`.The problem is if i convert it into string i can add and retrieve the data.But i want to store as date only in my model.

```
void MainWindow::setUpTabel()
{
   QDateTime myDate;
   myDate.setDate(QDate::currentDate());
   //myModel 
   QStandardItemModel model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
   QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem;
   item.setData(myDate,Qt::UserRole);
   //Myview is also created and set the model to it
   m_tableView->setModel(model);
 }
```

The problem is i'm not able to see the date in my table.

Comment: Maybe you need to use `Qt::DisplayRole` instead?

Comment: Yeah but that means to say that qdate is a string. I want it to be in date type only.

Comment: Not exactly. It will be visible as a string, but internally it stored as a QVariant, and you can get it with data() function.

Comment: yeah thanks,but if i use QVariant::canconvert() to check whether the cell has date it will show false.

Comment: What do call canConvert() on?

Comment: Say if i export into an excel i need to check whether it is string or date and then i need to export .So i will check using canConvert() on each qvariant that is stored in each cell.

Comment: @anbuselvan, but don't you know beforehand that the expected data type is `QDateTime`?

Comment: @vahancho but how will u know if there is a mixed type of data in a  record.It is a dynamic value it may be string or date.

Comment: @anbuselvan maybe `QVariant::type()` could help to know?

Comment: @vahancho Yeah thanks the problem was i used QDateTimeEdit (widget) so qvariant is not able to accept it.

Answer (score -1):

As the documentation says, you must set the item into the model specifying the row and columng where you are going to set the item.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html

Modifying your code:

```
void MainWindow::setUpTabel()
{
   int row = 0, column = 0; // here you decide where is the item

   QDateTime myDate;
   myDate.setDate(QDate::currentDate());

   QStandardItemModel model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
   QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(myDate);

   model.setItem(row, column, item);

   m_tableView->setModel(model);
 }
```